# How to distribute state of BottomNavigationBar across the app in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigationbar

In my app, the navigation bar works fine between the tabs, but when I go inside of each item in my list, I want the navigation bar to be there too.

What I did is that I made it a separate widget, and called in the bottomNavigationBar inside the Scaffold of the pages, but the problem is that I am changing the state of the navigation bar in my main page only, so the state doesn't get distributed across all pages in my app.

How do I make the body of the page change in an app where there is not only one body, but many?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not code over here in your post and I don't know what you have done so far so I can only advise you to go through this post.

I know you might have already seen this, but still, try to follow and this will really help.

**Thanks....!!!!!!**

> https://medium.com/@lucassaltoncardinali/keeping-state-with-the-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter-69e4168878e1